# Only 311 devices supported (Google Play Store APK upload)

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I tried everything, removing permissions etc from AndroidManifest.xml , but nothing changes.

Play store:

Supported Android devices **311 devices 1 added**

[image: Only 311 devices]

Developed the APP with Cordova, with a Samsung Galaxy Tab A, SDK 21 (which is not supported when I publish the app).

AndroidManifest.xml:
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10200" android:versionName="1.2" package="com.yorbody.videochatclient" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
</manifest>`

Comment: Set the `SupportScreens` http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

Comment: Added all screens: Supported Android devices 253 devices (57 removed)

Comment: When I use the armeabi-v7a APK, then: Supported Android devices 9864 devices (9554 added)

Comment: Its the phone architecture http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/103515/filter-out-arm-native-apps-in-play-store you should consider that

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use the: **android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk**

and not the: android-x86-release-unsigned.apk

Now 9999+ devices supported, and its working.

Comment: Thanks - was stuck on this for almost a week!

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to check permissions requested by your referenced libraries. There is a high possibility that one of those libraries is requesting a permission which is not available in the device you want included.

Comment: But its working on my device in development, but in production its not listed.

Comment: same device and model?

Comment: I use the Samsung Galaxy Tab A for development, everything works. But when I upload the APK, The Samsung Galaxy Tab A is not supported..